# Need help in CSS nav Style

Tags: html, css

I am trying to build CSS nav bar but i am in a bit trouble. In my code, background box is collapsing with content inside it .My question is why it is collapsing and can it be solved by not giving height to the box.Here is my code.
HTML

```
<div class="item">
        <ul>
            <li>Item 1</li>
            <li>Item 2</li>
            <li>Item 3</li>
            <li>Item 4</li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

CSS

```
body {
    color: #648;
}
.item ul {
    list-style: none;
    padding: 0;
    margin: 0;
}

* {
} 
.item {
    padding: 20px;
    width: 70%;
    /* height: 65px; */
    background-color: blanchedalmond;
    margin: 50px auto;
    border-radius: 10px;
}

.item li {
    float: left;
    width: 45px;
    margin: 10px;
    border-radius: 10px;
    padding: 20px;
    background-color: aqua;
}
```

Comment: set display: inline-block; and remove float. you can use text-align for ul.

Comment: when is display: flex used

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use `display:inline` or `display:inline-block` instead of `float:left`.

http://jsfiddle.net/x2ubrrh3/

**Update**
When `display:flex` is used you have to stop the elements from floating afer your list is finished (`clear:both`)

See here: http://jsfiddle.net/x2ubrrh3/1/

Comment: when display: flex is used